# Google Apps Script Comparing to Arrays

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to compare two tabs that hold PO data. The first Column holds a PO number. I want it to check new data against old, if a PO appears in both and the new old data just keep the new data. I still want to keep all the old data that doesn't have the same PO number. I get an error saying "The Javascipt Runtime exited unexpectedly. Thanks in advance.

```
function Data_Duplicates() {
     var WNSFleetCostsSpreadsheetID = ""; 
     var WNSFleetCostsSpreadsheet   = SpreadsheetApp.openById(WNSFleetCostsSpreadsheetID); 
     
     var DataCleansedSheet          = WNSFleetCostsSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('data_cleansed');
     var DataAfterCompareSheet      = WNSFleetCostsSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('data_after_compare');
     var DataPoolSheet              = WNSFleetCostsSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('data_pool');
     
     // Get New and old Data and put into arrays 
     var ImportData                 = DataCleansedSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
     var ExistingData               = DataPoolSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
     var NewData                    = [];
     
     for(var e = 0; e<ExistingData.length;e++){ // Existing Data Loop
       
       for(var i = 0; i<ImportData.length;i++){ // Importing Data Loop
         if (ExistingData[e][0] == ImportData[i][0]){
             NewData.push(ImportData[i]);
         } else {
             NewData.push(ExistingData[e])
             }  // End IF
       } // End Importing Data Loop
     } // End Existing Data Loop
     DataAfterCompareSheet.getRange(1,1,NewData.length,8).setValue(NewData); //Put the Data onto Input Sheet Temp 
    } // End Function
```

Ok I tried changing the end to the following (Thanks to Diego for pointing out my error) but still have the same issue.

```
for(var e = 0; e<ExistingData.length;e++){ // Existing Data Loop
   
   for(var i = 0; i<ImportData.length;i++){ // Importing Data Loop
     if (ExistingData[e][0] != ImportData[i][0]){
       NewData.push(ExistingData[e]);
        }  // End IF
   } // End Importing Data Loop
 } // End Existing Data Loop
 DataAfterCompareSheet.getRange(1,1,NewData.length,8).setValues(NewData); //Put the Data onto after Sheet
} // End Function
```

Comment: Both data sources are around 4000 rows and 8 columns wide

Comment: For each existing, you're looping through the entire list of imported and pushing a value each time. So that's ~16 million rows. Is that what you want to be doing?

Comment: Defiantly not. I will try only push the values over that don't match and then merge the new data in afterwards. Or write them to a sheet and use .getLastRow to add the new data afterwards. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Comment: I think that will solve your runtime error. Also, be sure to use the plural `setValues()`.

Comment: `.setValues()` is not the solution to this problem. If you call `setValue()` (singular), you're only going to set a single value repeated across the entire range you defined, instead of printing all the POs.

Comment: Hi Diego, I have changed it so it only adds data to the new array when it doesn't match (to hopefully reduce the number of rows) and corrected the error of .setValues so that it will print. If I remove 'DataAfterCompareSheet.getRange(1,1,NewData.length,8).setValues(NewData);' it doesn't error.

Comment: You didn't really fix the problem. Check `NewData.length` and you'll see it's way bigger than it should be. What you've done is resulting in array of length `(ExistingData.length * ImportData.length) - Existing.Data.length)`... so 15.9 million

Answer (score 1):

If both the existing and the new data have around 4,000 rows, comparing them in pairs would make 4,000*4,000=16,000,000 comparisons ("operations"). If that error is related to memory, you might want to try a different way to compare the existing and the new POs.

For example, a faster option would be to construct a lookup table using the existing data. One way to implement that would be using a JavaScript object that has PO numbers as keys and the details as values, which will take 4,000 "operations".

```
var ExistingDataObject = {};
for (var e = 0; e < ExistingData.length; e++) {
  ExistingDataObject[ExistingData[e][0]] = ExistingData[e];
}
```

After that, you can go over the new data and update the existing one with new values. This should also take 4,000 "operations".

```
for (var i = 0; i < ImportData.length; i++) {
  ExistingDataObject[ImportData[i][0]] = ImportData[i];
}
```

The result is that `ExistingDataObject` has all the original PO number with updated details and it also has new POs. In total, there were 8,000 operations instead of 16,000,000. All that is left is to get the updated rows again from the auxiliary object and write them to the third sheet.

Here's a modified version of your original code:

```
function Data_Duplicates() {
  var WNSFleetCostsSpreadsheetID = ""; 
  var WNSFleetCostsSpreadsheet   = SpreadsheetApp.openById(WNSFleetCostsSpreadsheetID); 
  
  var DataCleansedSheet          = WNSFleetCostsSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('data_cleansed');
  var DataAfterCompareSheet      = WNSFleetCostsSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('data_after_compare');
  var DataPoolSheet              = WNSFleetCostsSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('data_pool');
  
  // Get New and old Data and put into arrays 
  var ImportData                 = DataCleansedSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var ExistingData               = DataPoolSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var NewData                    = [];
  
  // Creates a JS object with the existing data
  var ExistingDataObject = {};
  for (var e = 0; e < ExistingData.length; e++) {
    ExistingDataObject[ExistingData[e][0]] = ExistingData[e];
  }
   
  // Replace existing data with new values from imported data or add new data
  for (var i = 0; i < ImportData.length; i++) {
    ExistingDataObject[ImportData[i][0]] = ImportData[i];
  }
  
  // Get rows from JS object
  NewData = Object.values(ExistingDataObject);

  // Write updated data
  DataAfterCompareSheet.getRange(1,1,NewData.length,NewData[0].length).setValues(NewData);
}
```